# Nuxt3 and Firebase Cloud Functions: Where to place Firebase cloud functions in the /server directory?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, nuxtjs3

I successfully was able to deploy my Nuxt 3 app to Firebase hosting using Firebase cloud functions. Now, I want to create another Firebase cloud function that automatically runs some backend code in response to events triggered by Firebase Firestore database.

As a test, I wanted to add the following simple "Hello World" Http function as a test:

`server/api/functions/helloWorld.js`:

```js
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions'

export default defineEventHandler(() => {
  return functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    console.log(request)
    return response.send('Hello from Firebase!')
  })
})
```

I ran `npm run  build` and saw the file in `.output/server/chunks` . Then, I ran the firebase emulator to test : I typed in `http://localhost:5001/<myprojectid>/us-central1/server/api/functions/helloWorld` **but get the following server error:**

**`{"url":"/api/functions/helloWorld","statusCode":404,"statusMessage":"Not Found","message":"Not Found","description":""}`**

However, when I try to access my other functions, I have no problem (ie, `/server/api/posts/all`):

This is the makeup of a "working" function (not an Http Cloud Function, though):

`/server/api/posts/all.ts`:

```js
import { firestore } from '@/server/utils/firebase'

export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
  const colRef = firestore.collection('posts').orderBy('createdAt', 'desc')
  const querySnapshot = await colRef.get()
  const posts = []
  querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    if (doc.data().public_id) // ensure we only show posts with images
    posts.push(doc.data())
  })
  return {
    posts
  }
})
```

**How can I access the Firebase Function (`helloWorld`)?**

Here is my `firebase.json` file:

```json
{
  "functions": {
    "source": ".output/server"
  },
  "hosting": [
    {
      "site": "<removed>",
      "public": ".output/public",
      "ignore": [
        "firebase.json",
        "**/.*",
        "**/node_modules/**"
      ],
      "cleanUrls": true,
      "rewrites": [
        {
          "source": "**",
          "function": "server"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using firebase preset, nuxt3 only treats functions as renderer. Here is the recommend way [How to add additional firebase functions when deploying nuxt to firebase](https://github.com/nuxt/framework/discussions/2414)

Or you can write scripts to copy files and combine index.js, and run it at predeploy